# Hashtable Collision Handling

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, hashtable

I have a hashtable with 11 buckets. And have to decide between the hashfunktion

`h(k)= k mod 6 or h(k)= k mod 10`

Which one is the best solution? I think it is `h(k)= k mod 10` because with `h(k)= k mod 6` there can point 2 or 3 keys to the same bucket.

And I thought when you have `h(k)= k mod 10` the minimum of the buckets have to be 10.

thanks for help.

Comment: You need to use something that can return 11 different values, such as `k mod 11`.

Comment: this means when I have a array size of 11 values, and there is the choice between mod 7 and mod 13 I take the mod 13, right? @interjay

Comment: No, you take the mod 11. Taking mod 7 or mod 13 would be silly. Mod 7 would leave empty buckets, and mod 13 would need to be followed by mod 11 to give a valid bucket.

Comment: So my mod function must have the same "number" as the bucket size? @interjay

Comment: Depends on how you define hash function. Usually you take a function giving an arbitrary number and follow it by modulo num_buckets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *must* decide between these two functions, mod 10 wins, because it leaves only one bucket unused, as opposed to five buckets that would be unused if you go with mod 6.

Ideally, though, you should use mid 11 for an eleven-bucket hash table, because it spreads hash codes among all available buckets.

Comment: thx @dasblinkenlight. Sorry for the many questions. That means, everything what is smaller than 11 would be waist of space?

Comment: @flowers1234 Not so much space, but it would waste a bucket, leading to higher per-bucket load for the remaining buckets, more collisions, and lower performance.

Comment: thx!!! I have another question redarding to this theme, but I think that would be a new question, for calculating the average search time on a successful search :/ there was something like `α= n/m ?` (dont know what n and m stand for :D)